# how to make a gridview in J2me

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

Hi I'm new in j2me & i make a application in j2me how to create a grid view in j2me and how to insert an image in j2me please give me the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is you can easily achieve this with [LWUIT framework](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/08/14/introduction-to-lwuit.html) for Java ME application. You can use [Grid layout](http://javame-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/lwuit-gridlayout.html) and here you can set the `BGImage` or `BGColor` for `Components`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use CustomItem and draw the lines like table.