# j2me program to create a GRID menu?

Tags: java-me

I want to create a list of operation's in a grid view. For example visit this URL.

http://cdn-static.cnet.co.uk/i/product_media/40000186/nokia1616_01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807471/how-to-make-a-gridview-in-j2me) or this [page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?114235-How-to-Implement-Grid-Layout-in-J2ME)(and use **LWUIT** or **CustomItems**) or **extend "canvas"**.In this way you need to two pictures for every operation in grid view.One for normal state and another for highlighted.Here is a simple canvas that represents 4 operations in 2*2 grid:

```
public class GridCanvas extends Canvas {

    int highlightedRow = 0;
    int highlightedColumn = 0;
    Image[][] normalImageMat;
    Image[][] highlightedImageMat;
    Image[][] imageMat;
    int gridColumnNo;
    int gridRowNo;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public GridCanvas() {
        gridColumnNo = 2;
        gridRowNo = 2;

        normalImageMat = new Image[gridRowNo][gridColumnNo];
        highlightedImageMat = new Image[gridRowNo][gridColumnNo];
        imageMat = new Image[gridRowNo][gridColumnNo];

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < gridRowNo; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < gridColumnNo; j++) {
                    normalImageMat[i][j] = Image.createImage("/hello/normalImage" + i + j + ".png");
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < gridRowNo; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < gridColumnNo; j++) {
                    highlightedImageMat[i][j] = Image.createImage("/hello/highlightedImage" + i + j + ".png");
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * paint
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(255, 255, 255);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < gridRowNo; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(normalImageMat[i], 0, imageMat[i], 0, 2);
        }
        imageMat[highlightedRow][highlightedColumn] = highlightedImageMat[highlightedRow][highlightedColumn];


        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridRowNo; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridColumnNo; j++) {
                g.drawImage(imageMat[i][j], width, height, 0);
                width = width + imageMat[i][j].getWidth();
            }
            width = 0;
            height = height + imageMat[0][0].getHeight();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Called when a key is pressed.
     */
    protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
        int gameAction = this.getGameAction(keyCode);
        if (gameAction == RIGHT) {
            highlightedColumn = Math.min(highlightedColumn + 1, gridColumnNo - 1);
        } else if (gameAction == LEFT) {
            highlightedColumn = Math.max(highlightedColumn - 1, 0);
        } else if (gameAction == UP) {
            highlightedRow = Math.max(0, highlightedRow - 1);
        } else if (gameAction == DOWN) {
            highlightedRow = Math.min(gridRowNo - 1, highlightedRow + 1);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

In real samples you would to detect gridColumnNo and gridRowNo due to screen and your icons dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not go with LWUIT (license, library size, etc) and do not want to leave the screen rendering to LCDUI (CustomItem), you should extend Canvas.

I have shared code for an adaptive grid at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/touch-menu.html Feel free to use it.

At this sample all items are Strings, but you can change the TouchItem to draw Images instead.